# How to use Tracking Key in DD4T application

Tags: dd4t, profiling, personalization, tracking

I am doing a POC for Personalization in DD4T, where I want to store the information of the Pages, and Components visited and to fill the `Tracking_Keys` table for a session user. I want to use this data to personalize the content.

I am using the below code to store the Keys

```
//For tracking the page and component visits           
var waiPage = new WAIPage(pgModel.Id, this.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context); 
//For Storing the Tracking Key
Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.WAI.TrackingKeys trackingKey = new TrackingKeys(waiPage.User);
trackingKey.IncrementKey(keyword);
trackingKey.SetKey(keyword, 8);
trackingKey.ExecuteUpdate();
```

The `cd_wai_conf.xml` is below here

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Configuration Version="7.1"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_wai_conf.xsd">  
<Global>    
</Global>  
<Presentations>   
<Presentation Id="1">     
  <Host Domain="localhost" Port="3035" Protocol="http" Path="/"/>      
  <Personalization Enabled="true" Persistence="cookies">       
    <Cookie Name="TDS1234" Expires="39000"/>
    <Tracking>          
      <Timeframe Type="hourly" Multiplier="1" Autofill="true"/>          
      <Pages Enabled="true"/>         
      <Components Enabled="true" Max="10" Averaging="true"/>         
      <ComponentLinks Enabled="true"/>
      <Keys Enabled="true" Increment="50" Decrement="1" Averaging="false" ComponentLinks="true"/>          
      <Exclude>            
        <Pages></Pages>            
        <Components/>           
        <Paths/>
      </Exclude>
    </Tracking>        
    <CustomerCharacteristics PreserveWhitespace="true"/>
  </Personalization>
</Presentation>
</Presentations>
</Configuration>
```

Also I have added the entry in to the `cd_storage_config.xml`

```
<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">
  <Item typeMapping="Personalization" cached="false" storageId="defaultdb"/>
</ItemTypes>
```

With this configuration whenever I am requesting a page, the Page and the corresponding Component IDs are stored in the `Page_visits` and the `Component_Visits` table for the particular session user, and the `Visit_Value` column value increases with every page request. In the `Tracking_Keys` table the `Keyword` the value is stored as `400` for each keyword as I have set the `Key` as `8` and the `Increment` value as `50`.

Is there any class or method to fetch this information `[page visit/component visit value]` from the Broker in DD4T?

Update 1:
In our case the `tracking_key` Value is not changing on the basis of `page_visit/component_visit` as the `Increment(50)` & the `Key(8)` values remain same.

So by using the code `trackingKey.GetKey(keyCond.Keyword.Key)` I am getting only 8].
To set the Key value as dynamic (using the Page_visit/component_visit value) , I need to read the `Page_visit/component_visit` value.

or is there any other way to handle this functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Manas, What I understand from your question is you are facing issue while incrementing the value of tracking key. To increment the tracking key value, you don't need to read the component visit/Page visit value. I can see some issue in your code, which seems to be a major issue in not updating the tracking key value. No need to use `trackingKey.SetKey(keyword, 8);`after `trackingKey.IncrementKey(keyword);`. So final code you can try is:

```
var waiPage = new WAIPage(pgModel.Id, this.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context); 
//For Storing the Tracking Key
Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.WAI.TrackingKeys trackingKey = new TrackingKeys(waiPage.User);
trackingKey.IncrementKey(keyword);
trackingKey.ExecuteUpdate();
```

Please share if this is not working for you..

Comment: Hi Mukesh, This one solved the issue. Now I can change the value of the Tracking_key

Answer (score 3):

You can get the value using the following:

```
var waiPage = new WAIPage(pgModel.Id, this.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context); 
//For Storing the Tracking Key
Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.WAI.TrackingKeys trackingKey = new TrackingKeys(waiPage.User);

//retrieving cond from page.componentPresentation.Conditions 
if (cond is KeywordCondition)
{
    var keyCond = (KeywordCondition)cond;
    trackingKey.GetKey(keyCond.Keyword.Key); // getting key from the condition
}
```

There aren't any DD4T OOTB methods to achieve this.

you should add your publication id and host (you app url) in following

```
<Presentation Id="1">     
  <Host Domain="localhost" Port="3035" Protocol="http" Path="/"/>
```

Comment: End to end example http://rajmittal.blogspot.in/2015/08/profiling-and-personalization-using.html

Comment: @aman this does not have details specially for tracking keys. this is pending from me.

Comment: @RajKumar : I have updated the question to pinpoint the exact problem.

Comment: I was able to find the documentation in OLD **ContentDeliveryReferenceGuide_51SP4.pdf** and **SDL Tridion R5 Content Delivery Project Planning Guide 5.3 SP1_tcm89-17676.pdf** and **SDL Tridion R5 Templating Manual 5.3 SP1_tcm89-17683.pdf** and tracking config of `cd_wai.xml` was also there.