# tracking using WAI not working

Tags: dd4t, personalization, tracking

I'm trying to enable page visits and components visits tracking using WAI. We are using web 8.1 and DD4T. Enabling profiling using cd_WAI_Config i can see users table is getting updated and also I can able to increment the trading keys and Timeframe table is also getting updated.

But unfortunately there are no entries in page_visits and Component_visits even though for both tracking in enable in cd_wai_config.

I tried to invoke tracking using code as follows:

```
TrackDispatcher td = new TrackDispatcher(waiPage);
td.Track(waiPage);
```

still results are same and i don't see entries in page_Visits and Component_Visits. Do i need to add **Activate Tracking** tbb in all pages? Also, as we are using DD4T templating, i believe Activate Tracking won't work with DD4T templating.

Please suggest how i Can enable tracking for page and component visits in DD4T.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality works on the Sdl Web's Category/keywords. you need to add the "Activate tracking" tbb in the Page template, and add the category for tracking in CT's Tracked Category.

check my answer on this post for code snippet:
[How to use Tracking Key in DD4T application](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13649/how-to-use-tracking-key-in-dd4t-application)

try following:

```
TrackingKeys trackingKey = new TrackingKeys(waiPage);
```

i hope you are doing increment over your keyword which you selected in TargetGroup

Comment: Hi Raj, Thank you for your response. yes I have followed as suggested in your answer and I can able to increment the tracking keys. But I don't see any entry in page_visits and component_visits tables.

Comment: share your code snippet which you are using in DD4T app

Comment: Hi Raj, Please find below:

 var waiPage = new Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.WAI.WAIPage(Page.Id, Context.ApplicationInstance.Context);
        
        Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.WAI.TrackingKeys trackingKey = new Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.WAI.TrackingKeys(waiPage.User);
      
            trackingKey.IncrementKey("MyKey");

        trackingKey.ExecuteUpdate();